# NAA flag was declined for answer which was asking question to OP

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, not-an-answer

My NAA flag was declined for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37629104/2057919):

> Are you sure that you need to use respond_to? maybe use redirect_to ?

Why? Should I flag this as very low quality or is the NAA flag appropriate for these type of posts?

The answer has since been edited and now reads:

> I reread this question and it seems that I no right understand it. English for me is foreign. What exactly did he want to do? to pass arguments or redirect on the other page?

Comment: Well, after the edit it is most definitely NAA. Before the edit, you could argue that it contains some advice that could solve the problem.

Comment: @BenjaminW. should these type of answers(before edit) be flagged very low quality.

Comment: Not sure it meets the VLQ criteria - personally, I'd skip or downvote and move on.

Comment: The first edit is an attempt to answer the question. It implies that OP should use `redirect_to` instead of `respond_to`. The flag was probably declined when the answer was in that state.

Answer (score 10):

When I declined that flag (2016-06-04 14:27:30Z), I was still looking at [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37629104/2); rev 3 hadn't been made yet:

> Are you sure that you need to use respond_to? maybe use redirect_to ?

Answers should only be flagged as NAA when they don't even *attempt* to provide an answer. Even if an answer is comprised of a question, we're still capable of deducing a potential solution from that 'question' - it's one of the perks of being human.

Additionally, **this shouldn't be flagged as VLQ** either. Very Low Quality flags mean "you can delete this right now". Since this does attempt to provide an answer, I would decline a VLQ flag too.

Comment: Hi i had the same issue one more time in LateAnswer review queue. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/13006344). Here OP gave answer and just provided link for references. But this answer is flagged as Link only answer(as mentioned in comments).

Comment: Undeleted it, thanks @Sandeep. In the future, just flag something with an 'other' flag.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't decline your flag, but I've pinged the moderator who did. That said, I would have declined it, too. Here's why.

The original answer clearly implied that the solution was not to use `respond_to`, but that `redirect_to` would resolve the problem. You shouldn't flag it at all in that situation.  See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) Examples of actual answers given there include:

> You probably want a FileStreamOutput

and

> look at manual for preg_split, third argument

(Each of those answers also had a link, for what that's worth.) The point is that those answers *try* to tell the OP how to solve the problem. That they are not very complete and seem uncertain doesn't mean they're not answers.

After the answer that you flagged was edited, well, that's different. Now, it's a comment, at best, and makes no attempt to solve the problem. So, a NAA flag on that would be appropriate. In this case, I've already deleted it, so no need.

If you run across one like this in the future—a "Jeopardy" answer that is really an answer, but phrased as a question—the most helpful thing is just to edit it into shape. Rewrite it as a statement, instead of a question, then feel free to vote however you see fit.